# Input of image type with Razor Engine

Tags: c#, html, razor

### The goal

Render an input of image type on HTML using Razor Engine.

### The problem

I don't know the syntax (there is?).

### The scenario

This is the way to render an input of image type with vanilla HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="image" />
```

But, with Razor, how can we act with this?

### Knowledge

I've searched on the web but without results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `TextBoxFor` with `type` attribute

You model

```
public HttpPostedFileBase MyImageFile { get; set; }
```

In Your View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyImageFile , new { type = "file" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Static helpers and TagBuilder as below to render

```
public static MvcHtmlString InputFile()
        {
            TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
            builder.MergeAttribute("type", "file");
            builder.MergeAttribute("name", "image");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have a generic `helpers.cshtml` in `App_Code` that I add little scripts like this to.  You can overload/rewrite it if you're binding to an object or have a uri.

**helpers.cshtml**

```
@helper ImageInput(string image, string name = null) {
    <input type="image" src="@image" name="@name" />
}
```

**Usage in your view**

```
@helpers.ImageInput("/images/mypic.png")
```